# Non breaking space doesn't work when I use join() method in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

This is my custom method:

```
func title() -> String {
    var titleComponents = [String]()

    for elem in 1...10 {
         titleComponents.append("my element beforenbsp\u{00a0}-\u{00a0}afternbsp)")
    }

    return join(", ", titleComponents)
}
```

The result is that it breaks in places when I put `\u{00a0}`. How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: The line is broken in that place, since it should not.

Comment: Do you mean at the non-breaking spaces in `titleComponents`? That may be because there's a hyphen `-` at which it is allowed to break the line. Try a non-breaking hyphen `\u{2011}`.

Answer (score 6):

That may be because there's a hyphen `-` at which it is allowed to break the line. Try a non-breaking hyphen `\u{2011}`.

Comment: When using .strings file, the character is different. So instead of \u{2011} we should use \U2011

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4** I had to use all caps: `\U2011`

Example for **lorem ipsum-text**:

`lorem ipsum\U2011text`

Comment: Same here for non-breaking space through .string file with SwiftUI: I had to use `\U00A0` instead of `\u{00a0}`.